# Compile time hints/warnings on struct changes

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have a basic POD struct with some fields

```
struct A{
    int a,
    int b,
};
```

The nature of my use case requires that these fields change every so often (like 1-2 months, regular but not often). This means that I want to check the field usages of the struct after the changes to make sure everything is still fine.

The compiler checks that all field usages are valid, something like `a.c` will fail at compile time.

However, some of my functions should access and handle ALL of the fields of A. So while the compiler verifies that all usages are valid, it doesn't validate that all the fields are used.

This work/checking must be done manually (if there is a way to do this at compile time, please enlighten me). So our current design tries to make this as easy as possible. We grouped most of the relevant functions into one folder/library so we could check over them in one place. However, some usages are embedded in private class functions that would honestly be more of a pain to refactor out into the common lib than the benefits it brings.

It's reasonable to just rely on documentation saying "Hey, after changing struct `A`, check the function `foo` in class `FooThing`". But I'm looking to see if we can get some type of compile time warnings.

My idea was to basically drop a `static_assert` next each relevant function that would check the size of A. Most changes should change the size, so an unchanged `static_assert` would fail at compile time, pointing me to the general area of the function. Then I could just change the function and the assert.

So besides the function `foo` for example, I would have something like `static_assert(sizeof(A) == 16)` or whatever size. This isn't foolproof, as it's possible that changes to struct might not change the total size, but I'm not looking for something really rigorous here, just something that could be helpful 90% of the time.

The main reason why this doesn't work for me is that `int` and other data types don't have a specified size from the standard. This is a problem for me since my project is cross platform.

In short, I am looking for a way to signal at compile time to check certain functions after a struct's definition has been changed.

Comment: You could give the struct a `static constexpr int major_version = 4;`, put `static_assert`s checking that value, and change the major version any time you make a change to `A` that you think necessitates making a change to calling code for `A`.

Comment: This seems more like a design issue to me. If a user of `A` is supposed to access all fields if any is accessed, then why are the members not private and an accessor provided that enforces the requirement? Can you give an example of such a function and requirement?

Comment: This sounds like something you should use test suites for.  You can use something like [google test](https://github.com/google/googletest) to build checks that can be rain against the code to make sure it complies to your expectations.

Comment: @NathanOliver we do have a test suite, but I don't think it completely solves our problem. If we've forgotten to update the function, we've forgotten to update the tests as well.

Comment: @NathanPierson if you repost your comment as an answer, I'll accept it if nobody else gives anything better, because it's really good

Comment: @user17732522 without getting too specific, some of our functions are a bit too specialized to use a general accessor for. While I agree that this issue hints at limitations in our design, I'm not convinced that this approach is a net positive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to put a version number into the struct itself, like so:

```cpp
struct A{
    int a;
    int b;

    static constexpr int major_version = 1;
};
```

Then, in calling code, you place assertions that check the value of the major version:

```cpp
void doSomething(A a)
{
    static_assert(A::major_version == 1, "Unexpected A major version");
    // Do something with a
}
```

Then, any time you make an update to `A` that you think merits re-inspection of all calling code, you increment `A::major_version`, and then the `static_assert` will fire anywhere you haven't changed it.

Comment: Just curious on how static members work, does each object of A add additional space to store major version now? Not a deal breaker at all, just curious

Comment: `static` means it belongs to the class as a whole, it doesn't require any additional storage space for an individual `A` instance. `constexpr` means that it might not end up requiring any storage space at all.

Comment: @khuang: No, static members are not stored with each instance.